# quantityType(forIdentifier:) deprecated in a future version of iOS?

Tags: swift, deprecated, healthkit, deprecation-warning, apple-documentation

Xcode (I'm on v13.1) warns me, that `quantityType(forIdentifier:)` will be deprecated in a future version of iOS.

[image]

I thus checked in [Apple's developer documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkobjecttype/1615298-quantitytype) for a hint what else to use. Surprisingly, on the documentation it is not labeled as deprecated in near future.

Which source to trust in this case? And in case `quantityType(forIdentifier:)` is indeed to be removed in teh future, is there already a known replacement?

Comment: Not sure why this question was voted down, so bumped it up. Saved me posting the same question!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The code completion dialog is merely reporting what you could see for yourself if you looked at the same header that it is looking at:

```
@available(iOS, introduced: 8.0, deprecated: 100000)
open class func quantityType(forIdentifier identifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier) -> HKQuantityType?
```

`100000` means "the unknown future". There's no rush; it's only a warning.

But you might as well start updating your code now. The replacement will be this initializer:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkquantitytype/3778608-init

```swift
extension HKQuantityType {
    @available(iOS 15.0, watchOS 8.0, macOS 13.0, *)
    public convenience init(_ identifier: HKQuantityTypeIdentifier)
}
```

Comment: Ididn't know how to interpret 100000. Also nearly any example code in Apple's own documentation they use the 'deprecated' version. Again something lerned! Thank you ;)

Comment: For anyone just skimming answers looking for code and accidentally skipping the replacement (like me, took me 3 readings to notice it), the replacement code would be: `HKQuantityType(HKQuantityTypeIdentifier)` available iOS 15.

Comment: @vauxhall Feel free to edit my answer by adding a rewrite of the OP's code.